# _tds.InterfaceError when trying to connect to Azure Data Warehouse through Python 2.7 and ctds

Tags: python-2.7, kubernetes, azure-sql-database, freetds, azure-synapse

I'm trying to connect a python 2.7 script to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

The coding part is done and the test cases work in our development environment. We're are coding in Python 2.7 in MacOS X and connecting to ADW via ctds. 
The problem appears when we deploy on our Azure Kubernetes pod (running Debian 9). 
When we try to instantiate a connection this way:

```
# init a connection
self._connection = ctds.connect(
    server='myserver.database.windows.net',
    port=1433,
    user="my_user@myserver.database.windows.net",
    timeout=1200,
    password="XXXXXXXX",
    database="my_db",
    autocommit=True
)
```

we get an exception that only prints the user name

```
my_user@myserver.database.windows.net
```

the type of the exception is

```
_tds.InterfaceError
```

The code deployed is the exact same and also the requirements are.

The documentation we found for this exception is almost non-existent.

Do you guys recognize it? Do you know how can we go around it?

We also tried in our old AWS instances of EC2 and AWS Kubernetes (which rans the same OS as the Azure ones) and it also doesn't work.

We managed to connect to ADW via sqlcmd, so that proves the pod *can* in fact connect (I guess).

EDIT: SOLVED. JUST CHANGED TO PYODBC

```
def connection(self):
    """:rtype: pyodbc.Connection"""
    if self._connection is None:

        env = '' # whichever way you have to identify it
        # init a connection

        driver = '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' if env == 'dev' else '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' # my dev env is MacOS and my prod is Debian 9
        connection_string = 'Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},{port};Database={db};Uid={user};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'.format(
            driver=driver,
            server='myserver.database.windows.net',
            port=1433,
            db='mydb',
            user='myuser@myserver',
            password='XXXXXXXXXXXX'
        )
        self._connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)

    return self._connection
```

Comment: Microsoft supports/recommends pyodbc, and it looks like you might be using one of the TDS alternatives. Also, that's an unusual form of user-id, if you're using SQL authentication, you should only require the string before the @.

Comment: Yes, the user looks weird.... but i swear that's how it works (at least locally). If I just input the username without the @part it doesn't.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use ctds instead of pyodbc? When I've tested alternative libraries in the past, I've always found gotchas at some point. That's why I prefer customers to use the supported option. In this case, I tried to PIP a copy of ctds and test it, but it requires a compiler, etc. to be installed and I won't have time for that until tomorrow.

Comment: Not really, except for the fact we were already using ctds in another connection so it meant less time. Pyodbc now requires me to install drivers and reconfigure everything for it to work... and given that i already have my local env configured and working I think it should be less complicated to just fix prod to work with ctds

Comment: Please take a lokk here ["Connecting to Azure SQL Database"](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/azure.htm) with the note: IMPORTANT: Do not use username@server.database.windows.net for the user parameter.

Comment: Guys, you were all right. Changed to pyodbc, installed the driver and after a couple hours hustling now i have everything working.

Just a couple things. 
If you are using Debian like i was, the "Driver=" part of the connection string worked as  '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' and in my dev environment (MacOS) like '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib'.
Solved it with sth like this

driver = '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' if env == 'dev' else '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

Answer (score 1):

As Ron says, pyodbc is recommended because it enables you to use a Microsoft-supported [ODBC Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567).

I'm going to go ahead and guess that ctds is failing on redirect, and you need to force your server into "proxy" mode.  See: [Azure SQL Connectivity Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-architecture)

EG

```
# Get SQL Server ID
sqlserverid=$(az sql server show -n sql-server-name -g sql-server-group --query 'id' -o tsv)

# Set URI
id="$sqlserverid/connectionPolicies/Default"

# Get current connection policy
az resource show --ids $id

# Update connection policy
az resource update --ids $id --set properties.connectionType=Proxy
```